Maui Button click works only one time after GoToAsync(page)
(Visual Studio 17.11.5, Maui Android 14, level 34)

I have a mainpage with a GestureRecognize on an image.
I want to navigate as :
MainPage : click image => ViewModel : await Shell.Current.GoToAsync(nameof(TakeCopyPhotosPage));
TakeCopyPhotosPage: click on SavePhoto button and this save the captured photo ok.
Problem : This works the first time I run the application.
After that the click on the mainpage image does no more respond.
Can anyone give me an explanation, please.
Thank you ( below are the corresponding snippets of code)

It seems that the await Shell.Current.GoToAsync(".."); in the TakeCopyPhotosPage does not return to the previous method SelectNoteImage_2_Taps(object o) in the MainViewModel ?
When I click the second times (and following ones) the debugger output says :
Debug: Android: Unable to find click target.
File MainViewModel.cs
        private TaskCompletionSource tcs;

    [RelayCommand]
    public async Task SelectNoteImage_2_Taps(object o)
    {
        tcs = new TaskCompletionSource();
        await Shell.Current.GoToAsync(nameof(TakeCopyPhotosPage));
        await tcs.Task;

        var note = o as Note;
        if (note == null) return;
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(note.ItemImagePath)) { ItemImagePath = note.ItemImagePath = defaultphotoImagePath; }
        note.ItemImagePath = ItemImagePath;
    }

File TakeCopyPhotosPage.xam.cs
    private void SelectPhoto_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        myImage.Source = cameraView.GetSnapShot(Camera.MAUI.ImageFormat.PNG);
    }


    private async void SavePhoto_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string filepath = NotesApp.NotesStorageManager.NotesImagesSubFolderFullPath;
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(entry.Text)) return;
        string imagename = entry.Text + ".png";
        filepath = $"{filepath}/{imagename}";

        await cameraView.SaveSnapShot(Camera.MAUI.ImageFormat.PNG, filepath);
        mainViewModel.ItemImagePath = filepath;
        await Shell.Current.GoToAsync("..");
    }  



Did you mean the image.clicked event will not work when you get back to the MainPage from the TakeCopyPhotosPage?

No, it's the inverse.  I am on the MainPage with a little image.  When I click the first time on the image I immediately go to the TakeCopyPhotos Page.  And after output from this Page, hence arriving to MainPage, the second (and following) click on the image there is about 6 seconds to goto to the TakeCopyPhotos Page. And after a few "go and come" the program disappears (it closes without explanation)

After digging and tests I think that the problem comes from the MainViewModel  boldpublic async Task SelectNoteImage_2_Taps(object o)bold in code :  await Shell.Current.GoToAsync(nameof(TakeCopyPhotosPage), true, new Dictionary<string, object> { { "Note", note } });

Did you check the logs after the app crashed?

Sometime the program seems hanged and I must kill  it. But usually, as said above, there is a delay of about 6 seconds before click and appearance of the TakeCopyPhotosPage. The output window show a Davey! duration=5201ms. The fragment output is : [EGL_emulation] app_time_stats: avg=5241.96ms min=5241.96ms max=5241.96ms count=1
[OpenGLRenderer] Davey! duration=5201ms; Flags=0...,

I think I found the solution. Before exit of TakeCopyPhostosPage before click on Buttons Save Photo or Cancel I inserted bold await cameraView.StopCameraAsync(); bold
